# positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right' is not working in angular

Tags: angular

positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right' is not override the default positionClass: 'toast-top-right' class and the code are follows,

'this.toastr.success('Your Screen as Set to Default[enter image description here][1] ', 'Success!',{dismiss : 'click', positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right'});'

'https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTbCV.png'

the position of the toastr is not changed it shows the top right corner.

Comment: Try to provide some code on stackblitz or here, not the photo :)

Answer (score 0):

`possitionClass` cannot be changed dynamically. You have two option

1. Set the `positionClass` at config level. It will impact all the toast message position.
2. If you want to change the toast position every time then provide new `toastrConfig option` everytime.